# sklearn feature union

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline, tf-idf

The objective is to run a multi-label classifier using three inputs. Each input is an excerpt from a larger document. The pipeline has a preliminary step which vectorizes each excerpt using tfidf

x is a list of strings, each an excerpt.

The code below works but seems to ignore the second and third elements of the list..

```
def grid_search(train_x, train_y):

    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB


    parms={ 'tfidf__max_df': (0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
            'tfidf__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
            'clf__estimator__alpha': (1e-2, 1e-3)
            } 
    tfidf1 = ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words))
    vctrz= tfidf1 
    clsfy = ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB( fit_prior=True, class_prior=None)))
    pipeline = Pipeline([ vctrz, clsfy ])


    gs1 = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parms, cv=2, n_jobs=1, verbose=0)
    gs1.fit(train_x, train_y)
    return gs1.best_estimator_


classifier = grid_search(train_x, y_train)
```

I tried without success

```
    vctrz = [tfidf1,tfidf1,tfidf1]
```

I also tried FeatureUnion

```
TFALL =  [('tf1', TFIDFX1()) , ('tf2', TFIDFX2()) , ('tf3', TFIDFX3()) ]
#maybe the () are extraneous but without them I get a self less error

clsfy = ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB( fit_prior=True, class_prior=None)))

ppl = Pipeline([     ('feats', FeatureUnion(TFALL) ),   clsfy    ])


gs1 = GridSearchCV(ppl, parms, cv=2, n_jobs=1, verbose=5)
```

where TFIDFX1 is constructed as follows

```
class TFIDFX1(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):


    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def vectorize(self, doc):
        return vect.fit(doc)

    def transform(self, mylist, y=None):
        return self.vectorize(mylist[0]) #would 

    def fit(self, df, y=None):
        return self
```

I omit classes TFIDFX2 and TFIDFX3 for brevity which look to mylist[1] and mylist[2] respectively but are otherwise identical

This fails with the following traceback:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'TfidfVectorizer'
```

I would appreciate any help from the SO community

Comment: So you want the TfidfVectorizer to be applied individually to each column and then combine the resultant vectors? If so, what if both columns contain same words which in the result will have two columns (one from each input column)?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. X is a list of three document excerpts which I would like SKLEARN to treat as 3 independent variables. These excerpts  may or may not overlap.

Comment: In this case, look at this example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the three inputs are homogeneous, the tfidf step will not automatically across the array

Instead you must use a featureunion step and combine the three inputs as three separate tfidf sub-steps as in [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html)

Thanks @Vivek Kumar